# Cypress 10 Unable to show my folders when i run commond npx cypress open

Tags: testing, cypress

[image]

When I update the cypress version from 9 to 10 and run the command "npx cypress open" unable to show my folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you named the specs in the folders?

If migrated from Cypress v9, change the spec extension to `.cy.js` and you should be able to pick them up.

Or change the configuration for `specPattern` to

```js
specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
```

Comment: Great bro, you save my tons of time. thanks, dear.

Comment: Where in the config exactly do you set specPattern? Is it in the `e2e` object? I get a type error saying it shouldn't be there but I did follow the doc and I don't understand

Comment: Yes there's one in the e2e object and another in the component object. I found the error messages useful as a reminder of the correct structure.